# Querying consecutive outcomes in date order

Tags: php, mysql

Versions: Mysql 5.5, PHP 5.4

I have a database of competition results.

The table structure is as follows

`id` (INT), `date` (DATE), `pointsfor` (TINYINT), `pointsagainst` (TINYINT)

To summarise, `if pointsfor > pointsagainst`, the outcome on that date is considered a win.

The result I'm looking to display is the 'winningest' run, i.e the start and end date of the most victories recorded consecutively, the best "winning streak".

I have no idea where to start with this, as I have yet to deal much with dates.

Comment: The dates themselves do not have to be consequitive, right?  Just no losses between wins.

Comment: That's correct. In theory there could be 6 days between game number 2 and game number 3. It is the wins that need to be consecutive, not the dates.

Comment: There's no field for identifying a team / player in your schema. Does that mean that every entry in the table is for a single team / player?

Comment: Correct Rob. This database pertains to the same team every time. pointsfor are the points scored by the team the database is for.

Comment: Are there ever ties, i.e. pointsfor == pointsagainst?

Comment: adfaklsdjf - Yes there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to try and find a solution using only MySQL, but it was a little too complicated. So here's something in PHP.

**Using PDO**

```
<?php

// Connect to database
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=stackoverflow;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'password';

try {
    $database = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// Prepare and execute query
$statement = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM `results` ORDER BY `date` ASC');
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Prepare streaks
$streaks = $streak = [];

// Iterate through results and create winning streaks
foreach ($results as $result) {
    // Check if result was a win
    if ($result['for'] > $result['against']) {
        $streak['from'] = isset($streak['from']) ? $streak['from'] : $result['date'];
        $streak['to'] = $result['date'];
        $streak['wins'] = isset($streak['wins']) ? $streak['wins'] + 1 : 1;
    }
    // Append current streak to streaks
    else if ($streak) {
        array_push($streaks, $streak);
        $streak = [];
    }
}

// Find longest running streak
$longest = array_reduce($streaks, function ($longest, $streak) {
    return ($streak['wins'] >= $longest['wins']) ? $streak : $longest;
}, reset($streaks));

echo '<pre>'; print_r($longest); echo '</pre>';
```

**Using MySQLi**

```
<?php

// Connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'stackoverflow');

// Prepare and execute query
$results = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `results` ORDER BY `date` ASC');

// Prepare streaks
$streaks = $streak = [];

// Iterate through results and create winning streaks
while (($result = $results->fetch_assoc())) {
    // Check if result was a win
    if ($result['for'] > $result['against']) {
        $streak['from'] = isset($streak['from']) ? $streak['from'] : $result['date'];
        $streak['to'] = $result['date'];
        $streak['wins'] = isset($streak['wins']) ? $streak['wins'] + 1 : 1;
    }
    // Append current streak to streaks
    else if ($streak) {
        array_push($streaks, $streak);
        $streak = [];
    }
}

// Find longest running streak
$longest = array_reduce($streaks, function ($longest, $streak) {
    return ($streak['wins'] >= $longest['wins']) ? $streak : $longest;
}, reset($streaks));

echo '<pre>'; print_r($longest); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, that's nailed it. This example specifically focusses on victories as opposed to avoiding defeat, and has returned the club record of 11 which I have verified to be correct.

[link] (http://www.arabarchive.co/aa4/test3.php)

Comment: Bit of a broad question, but can the same be done using mysqli?

Comment: @NiallFH - definitely. I've updated my answer with a version using MySQLi.

Comment: I assume for doing the same for losses, it should just be a case of changing  if ($result['for'] > $result['against']) to if ($result['for'] < $result['against'])?

Comment: No, that'd find you draws. You'd want $result['for'] < $result['against'].

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've written some basic code that I think solves the problem, but I haven't executed it because I don't have your data set.

```
$query = "select * from competition_results order by date;"

$result = mysql_query($query);

// First we'll iterate over all the games and build up an array of streaks

$streak_num = 0;      // an ID we will increment for each streak
$winning = false;     // flag indicating whether we're in a streak or not
$streaks = array();   // game data for all winning streaks

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if(!$winning) {
    // we have been losing up until now

    if($row['pointsfor'] - $row['pointsagainst'] > 0) {
      // hey we just won, we need to start a new streak and add this to it
      $streak_num++;
      $winning = true;
      $streaks[$streak_num] = array();
      $streaks[$streak_num][] = $row;
    }
  } else {
    // we're in the midst of a winning streak
    if($row['pointsfor'] - $row['pointsagainst'] < 0) {
      // we just lost a game, breaking this streak
      $winning = false;
    } else if ($row['pointsfor'] - $row['pointsagainst'] > 0) {
      // awesome we won another one in this streak
      $streaks[$streak_num][] = $row;
    }
  }
}

// Then we'll iterate over the win streaks to find the longest one

$winningest_streak = 0;
$most_wins = 0;
foreach($streaks as $streak_num => $streak_data) {
  $wins = count($streak_data);
  if($wins > $most_wins) {
    $most_wins = $wins;
    $winningest_streak = $streak_num;
  }
}

// print the game data for the best streak
print_r($streaks[$winningest_streak]);
```

I believe at this point, `$winningest_streak` contains the `$streak_num` the longest streak.  `$streaks[$winningest_streak]` should contain all the games involved in that streak.

Comment: That doesn't help OP find the longest continuous winning streak.

Comment: This will give me the highest scoring margin. What i'm looking for is the most consecutive wins recorded, disregarding how much the team wins by.

Comment: Okay I've taken another shot at it.  The code above does not account for ties at all, though.  Should they break a winning streak?  Also it doesn't account for 2 streaks of equal length.

Comment: I noticed some bugs in the code I initially submitted. It was just setting `$streaks[$streak_num]` to the last game in the streak, rather than accumulating them.  I believe that's fixed now.   It's tough to get the code right without the data set to run it against.

Comment: I have used the code above, but not entirely sure where best to print the result. Would it be within the if statement which is contained within the foreach?

Comment: @NiallFH  no, it would be at the very end, after all of the code above.  Try something like `print_r($streaks[$winningest_streak]);`  I will add this to the end of the code above to clarify.  Only after the final `foreach` has completed do we know which streak was longest.

Comment: `$most_wins` contains the streak length.  From your output, I believe `$streaks[$winningest_streak][0]['MatchDateTime']` is the first game date, and `$streaks[$winningest_streak][count($streaks[$winningest_streak])-1]['MatchDateTime']` is the last game date.

Comment: @adfaklsdjf Perfect! Start date displays well enough. Although, there's something about the last game date it doesn't like when I use print_r ? Doesn't display at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure and it doesn't seem like the kind of thing I can debug for you over stackoverflow..